# Issue with Angular12 while doing build with optimization=true

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I have an issue in angular 12 in which I can't seem to see where my errors are because they are not showing the component the error comes from but only show that it comes from main.js. This is a very confusing and makes it hard to solve issues.

I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags (at main.5a123573fe857541fe05.js:1:1857379) only when doing ng build with optimization=true and unable to reproduce this issue on local.

Can you please help me on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8giWe.png)

CSS I am using:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 36px;
    float: center;
    p {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #656565;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

Error I am getting in main.js :
if(o=t.match(/^footer[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   p[_ngcontent-%COMP%]{text-align:right;font-size:14px;color:#656565;opacity:.5;margin:0}"]],data:{}});

How to get rid of this issue?
```

Comment: *"I can't seem to see where my errors are because they are not showing the component the error comes from"* Neither can we since you included 0 lines of code. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you click on the link (at main...js), do you recognize the code? If not then it might be an idea to update your Angular version since you're severly behind (Angular 17 is the latest version as of now).

Comment: Optimization=true removes all debug info. This is expect that you don't get more with it. Run your app in dev mode to have more information about the error !

Comment: @Cuzy I am able to recognize the code but code seems fine to me, It's simple css nothing else

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Strange part is that in dev mode, I am not getting any error

Comment: @Sharma I see, it might be helpful to include the code in the question if it was indeed written by you and not some internal Angular library.

Comment: @Cuzy, I am getting error in main.js like:  if(o=t.match(/^footer[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   p[_ngcontent-%COMP%]{text-align:right;font-size:14px;color:#656565;opacity:.5;margin:0}"]],data:{}})

and this is CSS I have used:
#footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 36px;
    float: center;
    p {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #656565;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

Comment: try `NG_BUILD_MANGLE=0 ng build` to keep some symbols. It could help you investigate